# "Failure during raster IO" when converting raster to data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, raster, r-raster, landsat

Anyone have any idea what may be happening? Here is my console printout. What's weird is that the first four `as.data.frame` lines run without issue but the last one gives me the "Failure during raster IO" error.

```
library("raster", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
library("rgdal", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.3")
#> rgdal: version: 1.1-10, (SVN revision 622)
#> Geospatial Data Abstraction Library extensions to R successfully loaded
#> Loaded GDAL runtime: GDAL 2.0.1, released 2015/09/15
#> Path to GDAL shared files: C:/Users/JV-Desktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rgdal/gdal
#> Loaded PROJ.4 runtime: Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015, [PJ_VERSION: 492]
#> Path to PROJ.4 shared files: C:/Users/JV-Desktop/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rgdal/proj

liMax <- as.data.frame(raster("D:/LiDAR/LiDAR/30_m/m_30_max.tif"), xy=TRUE)
CanopyBase <- as.data.frame(raster("D:/LiDAR/LiDAR/30_m/m_30_avg.tif") - raster("D:/LiDAR/LiDAR/30_m/m_30_std.tif"), xy=TRUE)

rawData.li <- merge(liMax,CanopyBase)
processed.li <- rawData.li[complete.cases(rawData.li),]

satMax <- as.data.frame(stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Max_2015.tif"), xy=TRUE)
satMed <- as.data.frame(stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Med_2015.tif"), xy=TRUE)
#> Error: Failure during raster IO
```

In case it helps here is the printout for the info on the last two files:

```
stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Max_2015.tif")
# class       : RasterStack 
# dimensions  : 5640, 8763, 49423320, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
# extent      : -1491300, -1228410, 2709840, 2879040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       : Max_2015.1, Max_2015.2, Max_2015.3, Max_2015.4, Max_2015.5, Max_2015.6, Max_2015.7 

stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Med_2015.tif")
# class       : RasterStack 
# dimensions  : 5640, 8763, 49423320, 7  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
# resolution  : 30, 30  (x, y)
# extent      : -1491300, -1228410, 2709840, 2879040  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +proj=aea +lat_1=29.5 +lat_2=45.5 +lat_0=23 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
# names       : Med_2015.1, Med_2015.2, Med_2015.3, Med_2015.4, Med_2015.5, Med_2015.6, Med_2015.7 
# min values  : -0.3208517, -0.5767694, -0.5474564,          ?,          ?,          ?,          ? 
# max values  :          1,          1,          1,          ?,          ?,          ?,          ?
```

I hope this is enough info and I am asking the question correctly. I am new to stackoverflow and relatively new to R and coding in general. Thanks for any insight you can give.

Comment: Does `as.data.frame(stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Med_2015.tif")[[1]], xy=TRUE)` work? How about `as.data.frame(stack("D:/LiDAR/Landsat/For_Joe/Med_2015.tif")[[4]], xy=TRUE)`? Is the hard drive given by `raster::rasterTmpFile()` close to capacity?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Both of those lines still produce "Error: Failure during raster IO". My D drive (data) is a 128GB SSD at 50% usage and my C drive (OS/R/Rstudio) is a 256GB SSD at ~50% usage. I also have 32GB RAM which should not be limiting even with these large datasets.